# Why i am restart tomcat server then my user automatic logout in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

i am very tired because my user always logout my springboot application. if restart tomcat server. My Application working fine without restart server but i am restart server then user automatic logout.

i want to user always logged in which server restart or not
please give good answer.

Thankyou

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The session is managed by your app server.

If you restart it, your session will be closed.

That's why

Comment: ya i know but i am manage session by spring default security and set session time out but if tomcat server restart then session not work and user logout. i want to user always logged in if server restart or not.